# how to set particular data from datatable in dropdownlist using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

My code is as below, here No error but `ddlcountry` and `ddlcity` are showing blank even database have value in country and city for particular row?

```
    Dim query As String = "select * from RES_HOTEL where Hotid=" + Request.QueryString("ID") + " "
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.Connection = oConnection

    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, oConnection)
    Dim oDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    oConnection.Open()
    oDataAdapter.Fill(dt)


    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        txtHotel.Text = dt.Rows(0)("HOTNAME").ToString()
        ddlcategory.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)("CATEG").ToString()
        txtaddress.Text = dt.Rows(0)("ADDRESS").ToString()
        ddlcountry.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)("COUNTRY").ToString()
        ddlcity.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)("CITY").ToString()

    End If
```

Comment: How many rows does dt have? Put a breakpoint on the line 
"If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then" and then hover over dt with your mouse. You'll see a magnifying glass. Click on that and view the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your DropdownLists to the `DataSource` (which is a `DataTable` in this case).

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim query As String = "select * from RES_HOTEL where Hotid=" + Request.QueryString("ID") + " "
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.Connection = oConnection

    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, oConnection)
    Dim oDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    oConnection.Open()
    oDataAdapter.Fill(dt)

    '-- bind your comboboxes to the DataTable.
    BindDropdown(ddlcategory, dt, "CATEG", "CATEG")
    BindDropdown(ddlcountry, dt, "COUNTRY", "COUNTRY")
    BindDropdown(ddlcity, dt, "CITY", "CITY")

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        txtHotel.Text = dt.Rows(0)("HOTNAME").ToString()
        ddlcategory.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)("CATEG").ToString()
        txtaddress.Text = dt.Rows(0)("ADDRESS").ToString()
        ddlcountry.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)("COUNTRY").ToString()
        ddlcity.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)("CITY").ToString()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BindDropdown(ByVal ddl As DropDownList, ByVal ds As Object, ByVal dataTextField As String, ByVal dataValueField As String)
    With ddl
        .Items.Clear()
        .DataSource = ds
        .DataTextField = dataTextField
        .DataValueField = dataValueField
        .DataBind()
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT :** Updated above code assuming that you are using `ASP.NET`. I also separated the common code into a separate function to avoid repetitive code.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer,
I have more than 6 rows in database
but errors occurs in "displaymember is not a member of dropdownlist"

Comment: is this VB.NET (winforms) or ASP.NET?

Comment: Updated above code assuming that you are using ASP.NET. I also separated the common code into a separate function to avoid repetitive code. I have put your code in `Page_Load` only to separate the functions, it really doesn't matter which event/function it is in.